# azure-functions-core-tools on Mac OS

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I've used azure-functions-core-tools NPM package on a Mac using npm 5 and node 8, however I've got warnings, so I've updated node to v8.11.1 and npm to 5.6.0. After doing this I've installed `brew reinstall azure-functions-core-tools` and `.NET Core SDK` 2.1.105 for good measure.

However running `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@1.0.9` or `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools` results in

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for azure-functions-core-tools@1.0.12: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   darwin
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Does anyone else has this issue? Mac OS 10.12.6

I have same situation on two macs

EDIT: I even found previous install of azure-functions-core-tools in a terminal window [image]

Comment: Weird, v1.0.9 targets at .net framework which can't run on MAC. No idea about the root cause. Guess the runtime requirement was missed before and has been fixed after reinstalling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mac OS, you should use `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core` to install Azure function core tools 2.x, which can be cross-platform. `azure-functions-core-tools` is 1.x and can only run on Windows.

**Update**

`npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools` now is also used to install 2.x core tools, `azure-functions-core-tools@1` is 1.x. See [docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#installing) for latest command.

Comment: Thank you, it installed! However I'm 100% sure that I installed azure-functions-core-tools@1.0.9 on both machines previously (.zsh_history had only @1.0.9 before today)